# I am not able to upgrade from 20.04.5 LTS to 22.04.1 Ubuntu MATE

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-mate

**It says problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of network problem, please check your network connection and retry**. I re-tried 5 times and made sure that internet connection is stable, but still it is giving me same error. I have also attached a link of image of an error.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbE6S.png)

Output of `do-release-upgrade` command

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                           
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,265 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1,266 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'jammy.tar.gz' against 'jammy.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'jammy.tar.gz'
[sudo] password for hackytech: 

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu-MATE 20.04.4 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20220223) focal InRelease                                   
Err cdrom://Ubuntu-MATE 20.04.4 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20220223) focal Release                                     
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs                 
Get:1 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease [4,316 B]                                                
Hit https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                   
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x focal InRelease                                                                       
Err https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease                                                            
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A8580BDC82D3DC6C            
Hit https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                          
Hit http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                             
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/jeanslack/videomass/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                        
Get:2 https://mega.nz/linux/repo/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease [2,993 B]                                                          
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                                
Hit https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                                                     
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/lah7/ubuntu-mate-colours/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                   
Ign https://proget.makedeb.org makedeb InRelease                                                                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu focal InRelease                                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/sylvain-pineau/kazam/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                       
Get:3 https://proget.makedeb.org makedeb Release [607 B]                                                                       
Fetched 7,916 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                  
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
None

Checking for installed snaps

Calculating snap size requirements

Updating repository information

Third party sources disabled 

Some third party entries in your sources.list were disabled. You can 
re-enable them after the upgrade with the 'software-properties' tool 
or your package manager. 

To continue please press [ENTER]

Hit https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                   
Get:1 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease [4,316 B]                                                
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x focal InRelease                                                                       
Err https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease                                                            
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A8580BDC82D3DC6C            
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]                                                      
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                        
Get:3 https://mega.nz/linux/repo/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease [2,993 B]                                                          
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                                                
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [11.4 kB]                                    
Ign https://proget.makedeb.org makedeb InRelease                                                                               
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                                              
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [10.4 kB]                                
Get:6 https://proget.makedeb.org makedeb Release [607 B]                                                                       
Fetched 140 kB in 0s (0 B/s)
Fetched 140 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                   
Hit https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                   
Get:1 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease [4,316 B]                                                
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x focal InRelease                                                                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                                 
Err https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease                                                            
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A8580BDC82D3DC6C            
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                        
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                                                
Ign https://proget.makedeb.org makedeb InRelease                                                                               
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                                              
Get:2 https://mega.nz/linux/repo/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease [2,993 B]                                                          
Get:3 https://proget.makedeb.org makedeb Release [607 B]                                                                       
Fetched 7,916 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                  
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x focal InRelease                                                                       
Get:1 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease [4,316 B]                                                
Hit https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                   
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                        
Err https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease                                                            
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A8580BDC82D3DC6C            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                                 
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [114 kB]                                                     
Get:3 https://mega.nz/linux/repo/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease [2,993 B]                                                          
Get:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99.8 kB]                                                  
Ign https://proget.makedeb.org makedeb InRelease                                                                               
Get:5 https://proget.makedeb.org makedeb Release [607 B]                                                                       
Fetched 222 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                   

Error during update 

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of 
network problem, please check your network connection and retry. 


Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

Comment: Make sure your system is fully updated before trying again.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add some details. What is the current Ubuntu version? There is no Ubuntu 20 MATE. Please add output of `do-release-upgrade` command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have edited the question with proper ubuntu versions and also added output of the `do-release-upgrade` command

Comment: Remove all 3rd party repos in Software & Updates -> Other Software. And also from `sources.list` if you added something there.

Comment: @Pilot6 where I can find this `sources.list`, I deleted all 3rd party repos but still getting same error. Can you please help me with how to delete from `sources.list`. I haven't explicitly added something in `sources.list`.